# Is there a way to exclude a subsite in Content Query Web Part in SharePoint 2013/O365?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I'm using a Content Query web part in SharePoint 2013 in O365. I want to include all items from the root site and all subsites except one particular subsite.

In the CQWP, I can only select items from the site collection, from a site and all it's subsites or from a list.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is "No", as you can see, we can't find such settings in the tool pane of this web part, which indicates that it is not supported by design.

Content search web part(aka CSWP), it should enable you write some complex queries with KQL to search the data you want(exclude from a site or a library), just give it a try.

A sample query text which is set in the CSWP, it will exclude the results from a specific site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIOPD.png

Comment: Unfortunately, using CSWP and even Search Result WP doesn't work with my client's SharePoint Online P1 subscription, because of lack of SearchDrivenContent feaure that Cross-Site Publishing feature depends on.

Comment: Although you have probably right regarding that it is not (easily) possible to exclude a single web site from the query, be aware, that there is a lot of things to this web part, that is possible even if it is not available in the tool pane, see this document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx. As a workaround, you can query all of the web sites, and customize your XSL to not to display results from that site. Paging in that case (if you need any) might be a challange again in this case, however.